# How can I read this JSON?

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to read twitch.tv API, but something is wrong.

This is the JSON data I get as a response:
http://pastebin.com/uzx4LXJg

This is the PHP codes.

```
$curl = curl_init();    
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?game=League+of+Legends");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER,""); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$json_array = json_decode($response, true);

echo $json_array['streams']['viewers'] . 'aaa';
```

It just shows "aaa".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When debugging PHP, always set `error_reporting(E_ALL)`. That usually either tells you what you are doing wrong or at least points you into the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`steams` is an array of objects, not a single object. You need to pick an index (or use a for loop).

Comment: I've tried $json_array[0]['streams']['viewers'], still nothing. Could you give me an example so I can get going?

Comment: You'd want `$json_array['streams'][0]['viewers']`